# Concatenating class properties into a single string messsage

Tags: c#

How would I concatenate class fields into a single string for this method.

```
public string PrintInfomation()
{
    string message = this.title + " written by" + this.author + "is" this.price "dollars, with ISBN" + this.isbn;

    return message;
}
```

Taking the first field title by itself works fine but I get an error expecting a `;` when I try to add the other fields

Comment: you forget to plusses around price.

Comment: Also, notice that `this.` is almost never needed in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `+` before and after `this.price.`